# How to add groovy expression in adf

Tags: groovy, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

Am using Jdeveloper 11.1.1.7 and in that I have a column "Service Provider" with values containing "."(dot operator) within it..For example "domain.state".. I have to display only "state" instead of "domain.state"..Means sub-string of domain.state..

How can I achieve this by using groovy expression?
Can anyone help?

Comment: Is `domain.state` a String?

Answer (score 0):

Any approach you choose from below will give you string `state`.

```
def str = "domain.state"

assert str.split(/\./)[1] == 'state'
assert str.substring(7) == 'state'
assert str.substring(str.indexOf('.') + 1, str.length()) == 'state'
assert str.substring(str.indexOf('s'), str.length()) == 'state'
assert str[str.indexOf('s')..-1] == 'state'
assert str[7..-1] == 'state'
```

Is this what you expected?

Comment: But domain.string is an example..Actual string will come from data control and will get stored in column and I need to populate this column data and display it.. it can be any random string..

Comment: @user2447044 The answer is also an example. Try to use the first approach which is generic and splits string on `.`.

Comment: okk..means in def str="domain.state" ,i should take column value?    If it is true then what will be assert str.split(/\./)[1] == equal to?

Comment: ... would equal to your expected result. @user2447044

Comment: I have used above methods..But still complete string is displaying ,not splited..